# Grails 3.1.5 integration vs functional testing

Tags: grails, build.gradle, functional-testing, spock, geb

I added geb/spock to my build.gradle and my project compiles as expected.  However, I am confused with the difference between running Integration tests and running Functional tests.

I created 2 tests with "grails create-integration-test foo" and "grails create-functional-test bar"

When I execute "grails test-app --functional", both tests for foo and bar run.

How do I isolated the running of bar?   Also is a geb.config needed in Grails 3.1.5 application.  I can not find any documentation that addresses that issue.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I am confused with the difference between running Integration tests and running Functional tests.

Functional tests are a type of integration test. Test execution in Grails 3 is handled by Gradle, so I believe you can archive desired behavior playing with one.

> How do I isolated the running of bar?

Simple workaround would be placing tests in different packages, so you can use patterns when running them, e.g.

```
grails create-integration-test org.functional.foo
grails create-functional-test org.integrational.bar

grails test-app org.functional.*
grails test-app org.integrational.*
```

You can read more about patterns [here](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/testing.html)

> Also is a geb.config needed in Grails 3.1.5 application

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/grails3-plugins/geb) `GebConfig.groovy` is not nessesary until you need additional configuration.